# Is it possible to reuse another function with a javascript file on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, module, sweetalert2

In my html file when i click button it will call a function in file home.js.

File index.html:

```
<body>
   <button onclick="ShowMyAlert()"></button>
<script src="/js/home.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the funtion will call another function in file cUtilitiesForm.js.
File home.js:

```
 var x = require('./cUtilitiesForm')

 function ShowMyAlert() {
     x.ShowAlertSuccess('Good job')
 }
```

File cUtilitiesForm.js:

```
function ShowAlertSuccess(title) {
       Swal.fire(
           `${title}`,
           'success'
       )
    }
module.exports = {
    ShowAlertSuccess: showAlertSuccess,
}
```

And then I click button it will give a error:

```
home.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined 
(reading 'ShowAlertSuccess')
at ShowMyAlert (home.js:4)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):52)
```

I don't know if this is possible or not

Comment: Your error doesn't seem to line up with the code you have shown. `(reading 'Show')`. Your code shows `x.ShowAlertSuccess(`.

Comment: sorry I was change name of function but I forget so i edit my post as above.